# ScrollView doesn't work in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uiinterfaceorientation

I am developing in `Objective-C`. I am using the following code for `scrollView`, and it works fine in Portrait orientation.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
   UIScrollView *scrollView = self.scrollview;
   [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0,3100.0)];
}
```

But the `view` does not slide down when I change to landscape orientation.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Where you are initializing your scroll view? Can you add that part of code too?

Comment: I only setting the scroll view in the above code.

Comment: move this code to - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method.

Answer (score 0):

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0,3100.0)];
```

In this, 320 used for Width.. When you are trying for landscape orientation. Then please increase size for width..

Please check it with more than 320 (Minimum Screeen Width).

3.5 inch - 480 & 4 inch - 568

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH + YOUR_EXTRA_SIZE,3100.0)];
```

Hopefully, it will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   UIScrollView *scrollView = self.scrollview;
   [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0,3100.0)];
}
```

Scrollview always loaded in portrait mode in `viewDidLoad/loadView` method, so what ever adjustment you like to made you have to do those changes in `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear` methods.

Answer (score 0):

When Device get rotate **didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation** method get called, so I would suggest to change the ScrollView Contant size  this way

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size;
}
```

Note : Make sure your have UIScrollView and UIView in your layout

```
UIScrollView is scrollView and
UIView is contentView
```